# loop through an Excel range and write to the cells in .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, excel

I am trying to loop through a range and write values into the cells of that range. I'm getting an exception when giving the instantiated range an actual value.

what am I doing wrong?

```
int fieldcount = dr.FieldCount;
for (int f = 0; f < fieldcount; f++) {
    Excel.Range chartRange;
    int count = 1;
    chartRange = sheet.Range["B43:043"];

    foreach(Excel.Range cell in chartRange.Cells) {
        Debug.Print(cell.Address, cell.Value);
    }
}
```

I've also tried setting the range as follows:

```
sheet.get_Range("B43", "043");
```

The exception I'm getting is `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

Comment: chartRange = sheet.Range["B43:043"];   043?  You sure thats right?

Comment: You should also consider not iterating through the cells, because it is a fairly slow process, especially when a "large" range is involved; Instead, consider writing a whole block of data via an array: http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/Write-data-to-an-Excel-worksheet-with-C-fast.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Think you have a typo in your range. "043" (the number 43 with a leading zero) is not a valid cell reference. Are you intending: sheet.Range["B43:O43"] ?

Comment: Thank you Eddy! I feel like an idiot, but thanks. haha